# Continuously numbered list

Tags: xslt

I am using XSLT to convert an XML document to an HTML document.

The XML document contains a `<list>` element at different points (the list is interrupted by standard paragraphs) that I am converting to an `<ol>`.

I would like the points within the list to be numbered as one continuous series through the document.

My current solution involves setting a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="start">
   <xsl:number level="any" from="body" count="list"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

The variable is then used to set the attribute value:

```
<xsl:template match="list"> 
    <ol start="{$start}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>
```

However, the generated HTML document contains an empty attribute:

```
<ol start="">
```

The result is a numbered list that restarts from 1 with every `<ol>` element.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable isn't within the `xsl:template` we can only assume you have declared it as a global variable, in which case its value will never change.

Try using a function instead (requires XSLT 2.0+):

```
<xsl:function name="f:start" as="xs:string">
   <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
   <xsl:number select="$node" level="any" from="body" count="list"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and then `<ol start="{f:start(.)}">`

Alternatively (and this also works in XSLT 1.0) you can do this with an attribute set:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="start-number">
  <xsl:attribute name="start">
    <xsl:number level="any" from="body" count="list"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

and then `<ol xsl:use-attribute-sets="start-number">`

Comment: Thank you Michael for taking the time to answer my question. The first solution was not accepted by my converter (even after changing </xsl:variable> to </xsl:function>). The second solution produced the desired result.

Comment: Edited to correct and clarify.

Comment: Note, if you want XSLT 1.0 answers to XSLT questions it's best to make this clear when asking. XSLT 1.0 is now 22½ years old.